# reading multiple files from s3 using airflow?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow

Is there any other options to read '.xml' file from S3 bucket rather than downloading it to a local path, which i need to inserted to my mysql table.

I just tried s3 hooks connection which has download_file method that downloads file to the local
system, but i just need to read and insert into a mysql table in the run time.